# Limit size of uploaded images in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

How can I "resize" an image uploaded in wordpress.

If I want to upload an image with a "real" size of 1000 x 1000 pixels and only want it to be saved in wordpress as 500 x 500 pixels.

Comment: Check out this post on WPSE, [Automatically replace original uploaded image with large image size](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63707/automatically-replace-original-uploaded-image-with-large-image-size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at WordPress's add_image_size() and remove_image_size() function.

You will need to add the code into your functions file.

```
function wpdocs_remove_then_add_image_sizes() {
    remove_image_size( 'image-name' );
    add_image_size( 'image-name', 500, 500, true );
}
add_action('init', 'wpdocs_remove_then_add_image_sizes');
```

[add_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

[remove_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_image_size/)

You can also do a mass remove of image size using the following code

```
function remove_extra_image_sizes() {
    foreach ( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $size ) {
        if ( in_array( $size, array( 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'medium_large', 'large' ) ) ) {
            remove_image_size( $size );
        }
    }
    add_image_size( 'image-name', 500, 500, true );
}

add_action('init', 'remove_extra_image_sizes');
```